# Can we rule out sets like $R:=\{r,\{r\},\{\{r\}\},...| r\in R \land urel(r)\}$ in a set theory with regularity and urelements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Sorry if the question is asked sloppily (I'm not a set theorist), but can we generally rule out the existence of a set like $R:=\{r,\{...,r,...\},\{...,\{...,r,...\},...\},...| r\in R \land urel(r)\}$ in a set theory with the axiom of regularity and urelements? (Is there any such set theory that is worked out?) A simpler version of the question would be for $R:=\{r,\{r\},\{\{r\}\},...| r\in R \land urel(r)\}$. Looking at the regularity axiom in ZFC, there's no mention of urelements (of course because there are no such things in ZFC), but I wonder if there's any other way to ban such sets in a system where urelements do exist.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to ask.  Are you asking for a formal statement of an axiom that would rule out the existence of such sets?

Comment: In any case, it's not clear to me *why* you would want to not allow such sets--this would require you to give up or somehow weaken the axiom schema of Replacement (or else remove the axiom of Infinity), for instance.

Comment: Yes, @EricWofsey, a formal statement of such an axiom, or if the non-existence of such a set is already provable in a system that accommodates both the regularity axiom and urelements (e.g., ZFC with urelements allowed); in which case how do we prove this exactly?

Comment: I need such sets not to exist for certain semantic purposes. (If they exist, a certain operator in some axiomatic system could allow for reflexivity; I want to rule out reflexivity.)

Comment: The *existence* of these sets is already provable in all the systems that I am familiar with.

Comment: I see. How do we then make them go away, exactly? E.g., how does weakening Replacement do that for us?

Comment: Well, this is why I asked why you don't want to allow them.  You're going to have to get rid of some axiom that is usually desirable.  Whether this makes sense to do depends a lot on what your actual goal is.

Comment: Replacement is just the main axiom you would use to prove the existence of such a set.  For a fixed urelement $r$, you can define a function on $\mathbb{N}$ that takes a natural number $n$ to some specific set where $r$ is "nested" $n$ times, and then Replacement says that the image of this function is a set.

Comment: Although now that I read more closely I'm not sure I even understand what kind of sets you are talking about.  As written, $R=\emptyset$ would satisfy the equation $R=\{r,\{r\},\{\{r\}\},...| r\in R \land urel(r)\}$ (vacuously, since there is no $r$ satisfying the conditions on the right).

Comment: @EricWofsey good point; I'm assuming that $R$ is non-empty.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm very much happy to mutilate from or add to some set theory as much as needed, to rule out such sets, as long as the system remains consistent. The only role that the resulting set theory would be playing is to prove the consistency of certain axioms in an axiomatic system.

Comment: Well if your goal is just to prove something is consistent, I think it would make more sense to just explicitly construct a model of it.  Then you can just build a model of the thing you are actually interested in, instead of trying to build some artificial set-theoretic axioms that imply it (given that you would have to build a model anyways to prove those set-theoretic axioms are consistent).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is primarily to make something explicit which was stated in the comments.

In ordinary set theory, we have the axioms of infinity and replacement. If we have any $r$, these axioms together allow us to form the set $\{r, \{r\}, \{\{r\}\}, ...\}$ for every specific $r$. We do this by defining $f_r(0) = r$, $f_r(S(n)) = \{f_r(n)\}$ using recursion on $\mathbb{N}$ - then the desired set is $\{f_r(n) | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

It's also possible to interpret your set as $S = \{f_r(n) | n \in \mathbb{N}, r$ a urelement$\}$. That is, if $u$ and $v$ are both urelements, the set would contain $u$, $\{u\}$, $\{v\}$, etc. If the class of urelemenets forms a set (which it usually does), the set $S = \{f_r(n) | n \in \mathbb{N}, r$ a urelement$\}$ exists by the axiom of replacement again. Conversely, if $S$ exists, then the class of urelements forms a set, since the class of urelements is a subclass of $S$.

Comment: Thanks! So I gather that the only way to rule out such sets would be to weaken either of the axioms of replacement or infinity?

Comment: @Ak9 Not only would you need to weaken one or more of these axioms, you would also have to add in an axiom which contradicts them. Just getting rid of the axioms doesn't make the axioms false.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. By the way, now that we can have sets like the ones I've described (unless of course somehow we ban ways that can ground their existence), I wonder if we could also have sets like $S:=\{w, \{v, \{s, \{u, \{....\}\}\}\}\}$ in such systems where urelements are added, where the letters stand for urelements.

Comment: @Ak9 The axiom of foundation implies there cannot be an infinite sequence $x_1 \ni x_2 \ni ...$. So the example you're thinking of is not allowed in ordinary set theory.